# How to resolve (javaVersionNum != sparkJavaVersion) when starting SparkR in RStudio

Tags: sparkr

I get the following error:

> Error in if (javaVersionNum != sparkJavaVersion) { : 
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

when I try to start a SparkR session in Rstudio.

How can I possibly resolve this?

Comment: Could you see if Java is showing as properly installed on the system? Depending on the system, the method of checking is different.

Comment: Yes, I believe Java is installed correctly.

Comment: can you run from command prompt `java -version`?

Answer (score 0):

The first check if the JAVA_HOME is defined.

`Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")`

Surely it is not defined. Not all java versions work. Version 1.8 works. To define it and always be sure it works.

`if (nchar(Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")) < 1) {
  Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME = "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_192.jdk/Contents/Home/")
}`